# Проститься, этимология

Tags: этимология

Доброго дня вам. Связан ли глагол "проститься" (попрощаться) с глаголом "простить"? Если да, то как-то можно объяснить это? Люди просили друг у друга прощения, если не знали, увидятся ли еще раз?

Answer (score 1):

Да, глагол **проститься (попрощаться)** связан с глаголом **простить**.

**Прощаться** образовано добавлением **-ся** к гл. **прощать**, далее от праслав. *prostiti, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. простити, также «исцелить», русск. простить, укр. прости́ти, болг. простя́ «прощу», сербохорв. опро̀стити, опро̏сти̑м, словенск. prostíti, prostím «простить», чешск. prostit «освободить». Связано с *рrоstъ; см. просто́й. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

Люди при расставании на долгое время просят друг у друга прощения, чтобы не оставить о себе плохих воспоминаний.

Answer (score 0):

Попрощаться означает взаимно обнулить накопившееся негативное, оставить (или простить) нам «долги наши, как и мы — оставляем должникам нашим» в широком смысле. Ритуал, но по большому счёту — необходимость.